# HDFS data distribution

Tags: hdfs, hadoop2

I am new to Hadoop and started learning it. I have a question regarding distribution our data on HDFS.

Suppose we have a 100 TB of data in the form of flat file.

1. Where we will initially load our data? On Master Node?
2. Does Hadoop distribute the data by itself on the cluster? Or do we have to do it ourselves?

Answer (score 0):

Hi please find the answers below,

Ans 1) Hadoop follows Master and slave architecture.

- Name(Master) Node.
- Data Node.

Name Nodes are Masters and Data nodes are slaves. Data stored in Data Nodes and in Master/Name node the files meta data information is stored. like block information where the file is stored, file size, file permissions and so on.
For more info you can read the documentation "Anatomy of a File Write" in Hadoop definite guide book.

Ans 2). Hadoop takes care of data distribution. In Hadoop, data distribution is done based on file size. Default block size is 128 MB which is configurable. If your file size is 256 MB. 256/128 = 2. Your file will be stored in 2 blocks in parallel and replicas are created in sequential manner.